# Get the count and size of the subfolders of media folders and media items for each of the medial folders inside media library

Tags: powershell-extensions, media-library

I need to get the count of all the media items and folders inside any media folder in media library. Then export the data to csv I am planning to write a script using SPE. Please help me on the same

For Example

A(Media Folder) - 8MB

A1 (Media Item) - 2MB

A2 (Media Item) - 2 MB

A3 (Media folder) - 4MB

A31 (Media Item) - 2 MB

A32 (Media Item) - 2MB

B(Media Folder) - 3MB

B1 (Media Item) - 1MB

B2 (Media folder) - 2MB

B21 (Media Item) - 1MB

B22 (Media Item) - 1MB

I am using below script found in one of the answer but I want the size of the subfolder also as shown above:

```
$mediaLibriary = Get-Item "/sitecore/media library"
$mediafoldersTemplates = "Media folder", "Node"

$root = $mediaLibriary.Children
$table = @()

foreach($rItem in $root){
    if($mediafoldersTemplates -contains $rItem.TemplateName){
        $table += ProcessChildren -item $rItem
    }
}

$table  | Format-Table -AutoSize

function ProcessChildren($item)
{
    $contOfFolders = 0
    $contOfImages = 0

    $children = $item.Children

    $result = @()
    $tempTable = @()
    foreach($chItem in $children){
        if($mediafoldersTemplates -contains $chItem.TemplateName)
        {
            $contOfFolders++
            $tempTable += ProcessChildren -item $chItem
        }else{
            $contOfImages++
        }
    }


    $objAverage = New-Object System.Object
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $item.Name
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name FolderCount -Value $contOfFolders
    $objAverage | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name ItemCount -Value $contOfImages

    $result += $objAverage
    $result += $tempTable

    return $result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ProcessChildren($item)
{      
  $foldersize = 0
  $allItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $item.Paths.FullPath -Recurse
  $allItems | ForEach-Object {        
      if(-Not($mediafoldersTemplates -contains $_.TemplateName)){
        $foldersize += $_.Size
      }
  }
  $folderItemSize = $foldersize/1024/1024;
  $folderRoundedValue = "{0:n3}" -f $folderItemSize
  Write-Host "Media Folder Name = $($item.Name) - Size  $folderRoundedValue MB"
  $childItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $item.Paths.FullPath
  foreach($chmediaItem in $childItems)
  {
      if(-Not($mediafoldersTemplates -contains $chmediaItem.TemplateName))
      {
          $chMediasize = $chmediaItem.Size/1024/1024
          $mediaItemSizeRoundedValue = "{0:n3}" -f $chMediasize
          Write-Host "Media Item Name = $($chmediaItem.Name) - Size  $mediaItemSizeRoundedValue MB"
      }
  } 
}
$mediaLibriary = Get-Item "/sitecore/media library/Project/Hackathon"
$mediafoldersTemplates = "Media folder", "Node"
$root = Get-ChildItem -Path $mediaLibriary.Paths.FullPath -Recurse
$root | ForEach-Object {    
  if($mediafoldersTemplates -contains $_.TemplateName)
  {
      ProcessChildren -item $_
  }
}
```

Try this answer once and let me know if it work. You can extend or reuse this code to get your result.

Comment: I tried but it is asking for Process value and after that it is throwing error: ProcessChildren : The term 'ProcessChildren' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:9 char:19
+         $table += ProcessChildren -item $rItem
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ProcessChildren:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I updated the example because I saw the issue too. Turns out there was a newline that needed to be removed.

Comment: Its working fine. thank you so much for your help :)